# .net regex into java @"(?<!\\)(?'M'[^|%])"?

Tags: c#, java, .net, regex

Can you help me to understand / convert follwoing .net regex into java

```
@"(?<!\\)(?'M'[^|%])" ?
```

Comment: There ain't no such thing as Java or .NET Regex.

Comment: @Vash: For all pratical purposes, there is. The .NET and Java regex implementations differ in some aspects.

Comment: @Vash: Actually, it could be said that there are - considering each have their own engine implementation. Ultimately, however, I agree that the expressions themselves ought to be universal; this doesn't alter the fact that languages use different constructs to achieve a single goal.

Comment: @Jens: Interesting, do you know some page where this is described ?

Comment: @Vash, http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html in the section "Important Notes About Lookbehind", for one

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in this? I'm looking at the `(?'M'` part. I think there should be something between the `?` and `'` perhaps...

Comment: @jswolf19: (?'M'...) is the same as (?<M>...): a named capturing group.

Comment: @Vash: Here's a comprehensive list: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: @Jeans &  Mr. Disappointment : Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex consists of two groups.

The first one `(?<!\\)` is a lookbehind assertion. It will match only if the previous letter is not a backslash. The second one `(?'M'[^|%])` is a named capturing group (called M), that matches any character except "|" and "%".

I.e. the regex will match "a", and not match "\a" or "%".

Java does not support the named capture, but

```
(?<!\\)([^|%])
```

should work fine for you. You'd reference the first group by number, instead of by name then.

Note that you may have to escape backslashes leading to `(?<!\\\\)` for the first part.

Comment: i have converted it to "(?<!\\\\)(?[$|^])" as suggested by you. but i am getting error

Comment: i have converted it to "(?<!\\\\)(?[$|^])" as suggested by you. but i am getting error java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 9
(?<!\\)(?[$|^])
         ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)